# Why do different places on Earth have different concentrations of particulate matter in the atmosphere?

Tags: thermodynamics, atmospheric-chemistry, diffusion

From the second law of thermodynamics, I would expect the pollutants to diffuse from a region of higher concentration to a region of lower concentration. The rates of diffusion in liquids and solids are significantly lesser than that of gases, however this must eventually lead to pollutant concentrations becoming the same everywhere on Earth. But this isn't what we observe empirically. Different PM<sub>2.5</sub> levels have been measured even in cities that are adjacent to each other. I fail to understand how this could happen despite the local atmospheres being interconnected.

I suppose that the variation in pollutant concentrations is determined by certain factors more significant than diffusion. What are these factors and what is their mechanism?

Comment: Earth isn't a big balloon and "particulate matter" doesn't diffuse.

Comment: Vertical and horizontal convection are much more significant phenomena for the spreading pollutants than diffusion, even for gaseous ones.

Comment: It might help to consider a simpler case. Why do some cities have more humid air than others?

Comment: Another version of Mithoron's view: Earth is not made by solidifying a homogeneous solution!

Answer (score 3):

Particulates are not *dissolved* in air, but *suspended*. Gravity operates on them. That said, sand from Africa does reach the Americas.

Also, the atmosphere is *not* in equilibrium -- there are sources of particulates and gases, such as water vapor from evaporation, and sinks for these, such as rain and snow. There is energy input from [insolation](https://energyeducation.ca/encyclopedia/Insolation) and geothermal processes (think: [Krakatoa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krakatoa)), and energy output via [radiational cooling](https://www.mcall.com/news/weather/mc-nws-weather-explainer-radiational-cooling-20190327-story.html). Even [Pluto has weather](https://www.weather.gov/fsd/pluto)!

Answer (score 0):

**Because the atmosphere is not in equilibrium**

If the atmosphere were a small closed vessel, it might have a chance of reaching an equilibrium where everything in it would be evenly distributed. But it obviously isn't. Water vapour, for example, forms local concentrations called clouds and they sometimes produce local rain. In an equilibrium, water vapour would be even distributed equally everywhere.

This hints at the reason for particulates not being evenly distributed. More specifically, particulates are produced by a variety of specific local sources. Traffic is a major source of many types of particulate, for example, and traffic is highly concentrated in cities. Moreover, the processes that *remove* particulates from the atmosphere (one, for example, is rain which is highly local) happen far faster than the processes that would otherwise distribute particulates evenly throughout the atmosphere.

In a system as far from equilibrium as this, the second law does not apply. But the key observation is that the *sources* are local and the processes of removing the particulates are far *faster* than the processes that would otherwise drive them to an equilibrium concentration.